# Wordpress ajax request and defined constants

Tags: ajax, wordpress, request, constants

I cannot access my custom defined constants (in functions.php) when I'm doing ajax request with:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_form_request', 'form_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_form_request', 'form_request' );
```

Accessible only standart WP constants, like TEMPLATEPATH.

Is possible access my own, defined in functions.php?

Comment: How are you defining them, and how are you calling them in the ajax request on the server-side?

Comment: I just did a test definition in my functions.php, and accessed it's value successfully from an ajax request. So we need more details of precisely what you're doing to be able to help. Are you getting other stuff back from the request, just not the Constant's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested something like this and she works just fine:

In `functions.php`:

`define("MY_CONSTANT", "I am a man of constant sorrows.");`

Wherever else:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_form_request', 'form_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_form_request', 'form_request' );
function form_request()
{
    // check your nonce
    if($_POST['whatever'] == 'get_my_constant_or_whatever')
    {
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        echo json_encode(MY_CONSTANT);
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: My constant is generated in 'add_action( 'wp', function (){  });' (in wp action, because ACF won't let access it values) from ACF (Advanced custom field plugin) get_field function. How I can get that ACF variable in functions php, in what initialized action, to access it in ajax request?

Comment: Because, Yes, I now have checked (your upper comment), if constant is defined in functions.php without any 'actions' (clearly), then all ok.

Comment: FOUND: ACF fields in functions.php we can start access in init action.